# skip record on id base in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

Hi first of all please go easy with me i'm new to mongodb.
I'm trying to select record on _id basis from collection in skip. Basically in skip method it's ask the number of record we want to skip.

```
**_id                       message**

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1    message 1
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2    message 2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3    message 3
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4    message 4
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5    message 5
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6    message 6
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7    message 7
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8    message 8
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9    message 9
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx10    message 10
```

I want to get record after _id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5". i want to skip record before this id.

so my expected output is below

```
**_id                       message**

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6    message 6
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7    message 7
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8    message 8
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9    message 9
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx10   message 10
```

Comment: Did you try `{_id: {$gt: 'xxxxxxxx5'}}`

Comment: this will not work because _id is auto generated and it's going to different for each document in the collection

Comment: Collections don't maintain document order, so you'll need to sort and filter based on something in your docs.

Comment: ok so let's suppose i sort record based on date in desc order but what if someone added new record at the same time. In this case i'm getting record on the base of date in desc order so when i skip record i'll get that one record again which i previously got.

Comment: @Roshando you use the default _id from mongodb ?

Comment: Don't assume `_id` has any ordinality.   Consider it a "random" key.   Do what JohnnyHK says:  use a different piece of data totally within your control to perform the ordering.

Comment: Why don't you sort on the message field? I see that has counter like numbers

Comment: @JulienTASSIN yes i'm using default _id

Comment: @Anban message don't have sequence order. i'm just added sample for message text